# Problema al igualar el texto de un control numérico

Tags: vb.net

Tengo 2 controles "`NumericUpDown`" y quiero que en el "`TiempoRealTXTB`" se muestre el mismo número que en el "`TiempoFacturadoTXTB`" cuando el valor de este último sea más alto.

```
Private Sub ActualizarNumericUpDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TiempoRealTXTB.TextChanged, TiempoFacturadoTXTB.TextChanged

    If TiempoFacturadoTXTB.Text > TiempoRealTXTB.Text Then
        TiempoRealTXTB.Text = TiempoFacturadoTXTB.Text
    End If
```

Si cambias el número de "`TiempoFacturadoTXTB`" tecleando funciona perfectamente, pero si lo haces con las flechas funciona bien hasta que pasas del número "9". Cuando llegas y pasas al numero "10" el control "`TiempoRealTXTB`" no cambia se queda en "9" hasta que manualmente cambies el control a un número con 2 cifras.

Comment: @Pikoh Pues Visual Studio me permite añadir ese evento en el `NumericUpDown` y funciona hasta que llega al número "9" a partir de hay tengo que cambiar a un número de 2 cifras y así vuelve a funcionar el código.

Comment: @Pikoh Genial! Ya funciona perfectamente, pues lo estoy haciendo con el evento `TextChanged` y la propiedad `Text` ¿debería cambiarlo por `ValueChanged` y `Value`? En la web de microsoft viene el evento https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: En la pagina que enlazas dice _Esta API admite la infraestructura producto y no está diseñada para usarse directamente desde el código._ Es decir, parece que `TextChanged` se usa a nivel interno y no debería usarse. De hecho, en la lista de eventos en el diseñador,no aparece,por eso yo pense que no exitía. Yo lo cambiaria,pero si te funciona déjalo si quieres. Estoy sorprendido la verdad, no conocía ese evento

Comment: Ya que no debe usarse lo dejaré con `ValueChanged` y `Value` que parece lo más correcto, mi fallo fue no pensar que no estaba comparando los valores como números, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema con tu código es que estas comparando `String` (que es lo que devuelve la propiedad `Text`) en lugar de `Integer`. Por lo tanto, como lo que realmente quieres comparar son números, debes convertir los textos a números previamente a la comparación:

```
If Integer.Parse(TiempoFacturadoTXTB.Text) > Integer.Parse(TiempoRealTXTB.Text) Then
```

El problema de base es que utilizas la propiedad `Text` y el evento `TextChanged` del `NumericUpDown`, que yo pense que ni siquiera existian. Lo habitual y recomendado es usar `Value` como propiedad y `ValueChanged` como evento. De esa manera `Value` lo que devuelve es un `decimal` y el siguiente código funcionaría como se espera:

```
If TiempoFacturadoTXTB.Value > TiempoRealTXTB.Value Then
```